# mysql left join не верно срабатывает

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, mysqli

при таком запросе,

```
SELECT a.id,a.title,ua.fullname,ua.avatar,sum(l.like) as rait,count(c.id) as comments FROM `articles` a
left join `likes` l on l.content_id = a.id and l.type = 1
left join `comments` c on c.content_id = a.id and c.type = 1
left join `user_attributes` ua on ua.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP by a.id,ua.fullname,ua.avatar
ORDER by a.height DESC,rait desc, comments desc
```

выдает такой результат и вместо 0 выдает null

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя в первой записи нет ни 6 комментов ни 6 лайков

таблица комментарии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица лайков

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

понял, сделал так, но правильно ли? и почему выдает null?

```
SELECT a.id,a.title,ua.fullname,ua.avatar,
(select SUM(l.like) from likes as l where l.content_id = a.id AND l.type = 1) as rait,
(select count(c.id) from comments as c where c.content_id = a.id AND c.type = 1) as comments  FROM `articles` a
left join `likes` l on l.content_id = a.id and l.type = 1
left join `comments` c on c.content_id = a.id and c.type = 1
left join `user_attributes` ua on ua.user_id = a.user_id
where a.published = 1 and DAYOFMONTH(a.updated_at) = DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP by a.id,ua.fullname,ua.avatar
ORDER by a.height desc,rait desc,comments desc
```

Comment: Он работает правильно. А вот у тебя логика неверна. Если основной записи соответствуют 2 записи из второй таблицы и 3 из третьей, то перед группировкой у тебя будут 6 записей, и посчитается 6, а не 2 или 3... Надо отдельно считать суммы/количества в подзапросах, а потом джойнить.

Comment: а можете направить в нужную сторону как делать?

Answer (score 1):

Подзапросы должны быть в секции FROM, вместо таблиц. В подзапросе - нужные подсчёт и группировка. Например, вместо таблицы likes должен быть подзапрос, который вернёт content_id и для каждого из них SUM(like) для записей с type = 1.

Навскидку получится так:

```sql
SELECT  a.id,
        a.title,
        ua.fullname,
        ua.avatar,
        SUM(l.like) rait,
        SUM(c.id) comments 

FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT content_id, SUM(like) like
            FROM likes
            WHERE type=1
            GROUP BY content_id ) l ON l.content_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT content_id, COUNT(id) id
            FROM comments
            WHERE type=1
            GROUP BY content_id ) c ON c.content_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN user_attributes ua ON ua.user_id = a.user_id

GROUP by    a.id,
            ua.fullname,
            ua.avatar

ORDER by    a.height DESC,
            rait DESC, 
            comments DESC
```

Comment: вот, что пишет 1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'like) like
            FROM likes
            WHERE type=1
            GROUP ' на строке 9

Comment: @Uvasya Ну это не я придумал назвать поле зарезервированным словом. Поправьте...

Comment: а можно вместо null чтобы выводил 0 напимер?

Comment: Можно, выводите. Для этого есть функция COALESCE(). Или её кастрированная версия IFNULL().